# I want to add a string ti url if it's not present and reverse procy using Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am currently using a service exposed at port 8083. My use case is I want to add "/service" to all the url if it's not present.

Like user hits -> [www.example.com:8083](http://www.example.com:8083) -> goes to Nginx -> (Have my checks here) -> Reverse Proxy and return result

so [www.example.com:8083](http://www.example.com:8083) should become [www.example.com:8083/service](http://www.example.com:8083/service).

Here is my conf file:

```
server {
    listen        8083;
    server_name   _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://some_service:8083;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx location directive accepts a modifier that controls the matching behavior for the prefix.

With `^~`, if a URL starts with /services, it is considered a match and nginx will not search for a better match.

```
location ^~ /services {
    proxy_pass http://some_service:8083/services
}
```

The `~` modifier tells nginx that even if a match is found, keep looking for a better (longer) match:

```
location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://some_service:8083/services
}
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#location_priority).

In your case, the modifiers are probably not even needed, as nginx will match on the longest prefix, so if you have locations `/services` and `/`, nginx will pick `/services` for `http://server/services` and `/` for everything else. So just add the two locations, both with `proxy_pass http://some_service:8083/services`, and you should be covered.

Comment: This did not work. The request url does not contain /service and hence that needs to be added by nginx. So if I rephrase the question, I would ask, how can I add a specific string to the url?

Comment: ```
location  ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://some_service:8083/service
}``` 
should catch everything that does not have service. (if you copied and pasted, note that I have services, not service)

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. I think we both are not on the same page. So when I receive any request on port 8083 I want to add '/service' to that.

Comment: maybe a redirect, then, instead of `proxy_pass`, because you want the client to see /service? If so, instead of `proxy_pass`, use `return 301 $scheme://your-server/service$request_uri`, see https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/